# Connect different region QLDB database

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core-webapi, amazon-qldb

I have created windows instance in eu-west-2 and AWS doesn't provide QLDB service in eu-west-2 so I have created QLDB database service in eu-west-1 region.

Now I am getting error when I use QLDB service from eu-west-1: The Ledger with name XXX is not found

I am using .net core 3.1 application.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide more information like your .net code for client instantiation (which endpoint you are connecting to) and what region was the ledger created in? As is we cannot tell what could've gone wrong.

Comment: Hello Ethan, I am using .net Core 3.1 Web API project and I am calling from eu-west-2 region to eu-west-1 region.
Windows instance is created in eu-west-2 and QLDB added in eu-west-1

Comment: Hi @Andy did you found a solution to this? I am kind of in same situation for qldb usage.

Comment: @KetanDoshi We need to allow different region in security